# Angular4 MdDialog appears but no html is displayed inside

Tags: angular, mddialog

[I'm not sure why the html inside of my dialog isn't displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8y1C.jpg)

Here are my app and dialog components. All of the imports seem to be working correctly, and I'm not getting any error messages in the browser console.

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {MdDialog, MdDialogRef} from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  dialogRef : MdDialogRef<Dialog>;
  title = 'Code Share app';
  admin = false;
  userID : string = "";

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog ){
    this.openDialog();
  }

  openDialog() {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Dialog);
  this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.dialogRef = null;
  });
 }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog',
  template: `<h1>Dialog</h1>
  <div md-dialog-content>What would you like to do?</div>
  <div md-dialog-actions>
    <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 1')">Option 1</button>
    <button md-button (click)="dialogRef.close('Option 2')">Option 2</button>
  </div>
  <p>hello</p>`,
})

export class Dialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<Dialog>){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the HTML selector "dialog" was in a namespace conflict with a selector from one of the libraries I'm using. I changed the name and it worked.